# Simple Product page not displaying add to cart button

Tags: magento-2.1, simple-product

Magento 2.1.5 CE

created a simple product, browsed product page.
No add to cart button displayed ?

Comment: which theme? product is in stock?

Comment: Luma theme product is in stock yes. add button is displayed when hovering over item in grid page before product page.

Comment: Any design customization? if you set temporarily blank as theme the button appears?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to do a **composer install** and the **deploy** again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ vendor/* app/code/Magento;
composer install && composer update -vv &&
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Look your configuration theme maybe you have some configuration above, otherwise you can do it manually with CSS since you say that the configuration product, stock, website, status are good!